# C# / VS2013 - Why does this code fail without debugging?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

Here's a program I wrote to test a basic threading scenario. It works exactly as expected when I run it with debugging enabled.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static bool keepCounting;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(countNumbers);
        myThread.Name = "MyThread";

        keepCounting = true;
        myThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)); // countNumbers() runs for 1 sec.
        keepCounting = false;
    }

    static void countNumbers()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} beginning count.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        long n = 0;
        while (keepCounting)
        {
            n++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Current thread:          {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of iterations:    {0}", n);
    }
}
```

However, when I set VS to make a release build, and run it using "Start Without Debugging" -- note that BOTH of these steps have to be taken, or else it will still succeed -- it mysteriously gets "stuck" somewhere in the middle of the `countNumbers()` method after printing "MyThread beginning count.", and it never times out and prints the result to the console window.

Can anyone explain this wackiness?

Comment: This may apply: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

Comment: In particular you may have to mark `keepCounting` as `volatile`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, yes. That was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop

```
while (keepCounting)
{
    n++;
}
```

Is, as far as the language is concerned, equivalent to

```
var cpu_register = keepCounting;
while (cpu_register)
{
    n++;
}
```

CPU registers are a lot faster than memory reads, so the optimizer uses the second version.  With predictable unhappy results for you.

Comment: Yes, that explains it! Using the "volatile" keyword suppressed the optimization, and made my program work properly. You folks are so knowledgeable. :)